# Computer will not recognize phone with USB Debugging enabled

Tags: usb-debugging, motorola-droid-razr

so I'm trying to test apps on my Motorola Droid Razr so that I can test with audio and video playback. I'm running Windows XP (woot), and the problem is that when I connect my phone with USB Debugging enabled, the computer doesn't recognize it even though it was just connected as a media device with USB Debugging turned off. I thought I downloaded the correct USB driver because it worked before without USB Debugging.

I thought that the computer could automatically find the new hardware because i had just downloaded it, however this leads me to my next problem: whenever I connect my phone to the computer it kills the computer's internet...weird right? I've tried turning tethering, wifi, bluetooth, you-name-it on/off and it still does that. Any thoughts??

Appreciate the help
Peter M.

Comment: Connect your device in debug mode; and on your PC, go to Control Panel -> Add New Hardware to check if the ADB drivers for your device have been installed correctly / properly (if not, the device will show up in the list). If not, there is your issue.

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies with the type of USB driver you have downloaded. They are two types of USB driver's.

1.Type1

2.Type2

Type1 USB driver is used only for file transfer and personal purpose like backup etc.

Whereas type2 USB driver is used solely for debugging(development). You need to download the Debug driver for your Motorola Droid razr

You had downloaded the type 1 driver so your device didn't get recognized by eclipse(or ADT).  In order to get your device identified via the debug enabled option download the latest debug driver for your device.

Follow this  [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#WinXp) on downloading the device drivers for your device

Answer (score 0):

Endless hours were spent trying to connect my Motorola Razr to my computer. This finally worked:

Go to Google Playstore on the phone. Download Motorola PIM (all upper case).

If you have an extended battery case/charger on the phone, remove the phone and insert the USB cable into the port on the top of the phone.

Or

Download [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) and connect wirelessly.

Comment: AirDroid is awesome...use it all the time